# Redirect users on logout

Tags: multisite, redirect

Have multisite set up and would like to redirect users on logout to the root site home page.  I know there has to be an answer for this.  But I can't find it!  driving me batty;-)  Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

you can use `wp_logout_url( $redirect);` as Pippin sugested if you are echoing out the logout link and if you need it for the built-in logout link on the backend you can use:

```
//function to redirect after logout
function logout_redirect765(){
  wp_redirect( home_url() ); 
  exit; 
}

//hook function  to wp_logout action
add_action('wp_logout','logout_redirect765');
```

Answer (score 1):

use `wp_logout_url( $redirect );` $redirect is the url for them to be redirected to.

Comment: geeezzz thanks.  I had tried that before - but in the wrong spot... worked like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

You can probably accomplish what you need to with [wp_logout_url( $redirect )](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_logout_url). I'd try replacing the logout link in your theme's template files with something like this:

```
<a href="<?php echo wp_logout_url( network_home_url() ); ?>" title="Logout">Logout</a>
```

There's not a codex page for network_home_url(), but there is one for [home_url()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/home_url), and it mentions using network_home_url() for a multisite install.